# Microsoft Excel VBA automatically click OK in a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, userform, commandbutton

Hi I'm trying to modify the XmlTools.xla plugin.

I have it set up so that the UserForm already displays with everything my users need prefilled.  I just need some way to programmatically click the OK button.  I tried using send keys in the code snippet shown below but it does not work.

```
Public Sub sbShowForm()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet555"

ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Name = "lastCell"

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Is this"

frmCreateXmlList.Show
frmCreateXmlList.btnOK_Click

ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) = "called?"

Application.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
Application.SendKeys ("{Return}")

CreateXmlFiles.sbUserFormOKClicked
Call sbUserFormOKClicked

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

frmCreateXmlList.Hide
End Sub 'sbShowForm
```

I realize this request is a little goofy, but I received user requests saying that it is "too much work" to fill out the form.  I know SendKeys aren't always reliable, but I'm just looking for something to get it to work.

Comment: I also tried frmCreateXmlList.btnOK_Click ,but that didn't seem to fix it

Comment: Are you sure that code is being called?

Comment: I used the debugger to step through and it looks like it is being called, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything.  I updated my code (shown above).

Comment: hm strange but try just `{Enter}` without the (). And make sure form is active and button has focus

Comment: I just figured this out.  My send keys were working but they were sending keystrokes to the active worksheet, not the userform.  

I updated the UserForm -> Properties -> ShowModal -> False

When this property was set to true it would not work. I can't answer my own question yet cause I don't have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out. My send keys were working but they were sending keystrokes to the active worksheet, not the userform. I updated the UserForm -> Properties -> ShowModal -> False

When this property was set to true it would not work. I also decided to use

```
Call sbUserFormOKClicked
```

because it should be more reliable than send keys.